# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,2]$ such that $f(0)=f(2)$, prove the following statement.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've recently come across this exercise for which I currently have no clue on how to solve.

Basically, it says that given a function $f$ that is **continuous** on $[0,2]$ such that $f(0)=f(2)$, you have to prove that there exist **two** points inside the interval, lets say $x_1,x_2\in[0,2]$ that are a **unit** apart, that is $x_2-x_1=1$, and that they both have the same **image**, that is, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

The problem is that I can't even see it intuitively. Usually I tend to see these kind of problems intuitively, realize to myself they *seem* to be true after some thinking, and then the problem arises at the time of formalizing my thoughts. But this time, I don't even know why that is implied.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $g \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}; \; g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$.

Comment: @L.F.: What if the points are to be 3/4 units apart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $$g(x) = f(x) - f(x + 1)$$

This is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$, and $$g(0) = -g(1)$$

So either $g$ is zero at the endpoints, or it changes sign somewhere between them. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: @Elucas I'm glad. One reason to consider the function $g$ I chose is because we have a statement about the difference of function values (so we'd like to subtract values of $f$) with a difference of $1$ in $x$-values. Once you find out that the conclusion holds exactly when $f(x) = f(x + 1)$, the approach is strongly hinted at.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, with that in mind I managed to finish with ease. It's impressive how many things in analysis boil down to finding a proper function to analyze, I just wish I knew when and how to apply this method.

Comment: Whoops sorry, had to delete my post and now it appears below yours. Thanks for the hint about the function selection, I'll definitely dedicate more time to practising this, as it seems to be appearing more and more often in my analysis exercises.